# Create Extension in Postigis

Tags: linux, postgresql, fedora, postgis

I work with Fedora 17 and  Postgis. I want to create extension

my code is

```
create extension test;
```

bu thows exeption

> could not open extension control file "/usr/pgsql-9.2/share/extension/test.control": No such file or directory

Comment: You might get better results if you fix the typos in critical terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming "test" stands for one of the [additional modules provided by Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/contrib.html), you need to install the software package **`postgresql-contrib-9.2`** first.
Available through your package management system. Probably RPM on Fedora, probably managed by [YUM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellowdog_Updater,_Modified) ...